# Return rows which are different in one DataFrame from another DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

There are a lot of similar questions to this, but none have helped me so I assume a nuance to my version which I'm missing.

I have two DataFrames: df1, df2 (of same dimensions which can me mapped 1-2-1 on unique column, ie Name) and I want all rows which exist in df1 and are different to the corresponding row in df2.
I've tried more elegant solutions involving .isin() and ugly solutions using loops. But nothing returns the correct solution.
I post below one of the less Pythonic solutions since I believe it displays what I am trying to do most explicitly:

```
    df1['hash'] = df1[common_fields].apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
    df2['hash'] = df2[common_fields].apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
    df2_hashes = df2['hash'].tolist()
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        if not df1['hash'].iloc[i] in df2_hashes:
            df = df.append(df1.iloc[i])
```

NB. The above attempt, returns all row whether different or not.

Answer (score 0):

Every row in df1 is not the same as the corresponding row in the df2.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 500],
      'C': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]}
d2 = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      'B': [10, 22, 30, 44, 500],
      'D': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df = df1[~((df1['A'] == df2['A']) & (df1['B'] == df2['B']))]


In [321]: df1                                                                                                           
Out[321]: 
   A    B    C
0  1   10  100
1  2   20  200
2  3   30  300
3  4   40  400
4  5  500  500

In [322]: df2                                                                                                           
Out[322]: 
   A    B    D
0  1   10  100
1  2   22  200
2  3   30  300
3  4   44  400
4  5  500  500
```

Output

```
In [330]: df                                                                                                            
Out[330]: 
   A   B    C
1  2  20  200
3  4  40  400
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original index does not matter, you can index both dataframe by the `Name` column and directly compare their common fields:

```
result = df1.set_index('Name')
result = result.loc[~(result[common_fields] == df2.set_index('Name')[common_fields]
                    .reindex(df1['Name'])).all(axis=1)].reset_index()
```

If you want to keep the original index values, you must save them into a column:

```
result = df1.reset_index().set_index('Name')
result = result.loc[~(result[common_fields] == df2.set_index('Name')[common_fields]
                    .reindex(df1['Name'])).all(axis=1)].reset_index().set_index('index')
```

Comment: I do think it is somehow related to index, but getting error:
`*** KeyError: "['Name'] not in index"`
And no, original index does not matter.

Comment: You said that *Name* was the name of the unique common column... Please add some data with the name of the columns of your dataframes if you want that I use them in my code.